# Need to sort a list of random numbers in a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, bubble-sort

I am in need of help in creating a stored procedure that allows a user to input a list of random numbers and then sort them using the bubble sort algorithm. I am very new to programming and as well as PL/SQL. Any help would be much appreciated.

Below are the lines of code that I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_BubbleSort (i_number IN number) AS

type l_array_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10);

l_temp  NUMBER;

l_array l_array_type := l_array_type();

BEGIN

  --Loop through numbers and re-arrange their order using bubble sort---

  FOR i in 1 .. l_array.Count - 1 LOOP

    FOR j IN 2 .. l_array.Count LOOP
      IF l_array(j) > l_array(j - 1) THEN
        l_temp := l_array(j - 1);
        l_array(j - 1) := l_array(j);
        l_array(j) := l_temp;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;

  --Print the newly sorted numbers user inputs 

  FOR i in REVERSE 1 .. l_array.COUNT LOOP

    dbms_output.put_line('The new sorted numbers are: ' || l_array(i));
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: what does your code fail to do? what errors do you get? what is your expected input and output?

Comment: My expected input would be defined by the user. So, the user would plug in some random numbers and the output needs to be a sorted list of those random numbers (using bubble sort algorithm) input by the user. Does that help?

Comment: Your procedure is taking a single number as a parameter, which you then don't refer to. Hows does `l_array` get populated? At the moment this doesn't do anything because there is nothing to sort or to display. If you populated `l_array` with random numbers then it would sort them, so that seems to be the missing part.

Comment: What other comments point out is that you posted some code but nothing else. Where your code is failing? Is returning an error or just erroneus data, nor ordered? If you use [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/)  to post some sample then you will get some answer.

Comment: Alex, thank you for the quick response. Yes, that is where my question lies. How can I manage to ask the user to input the list of numbers and insert into l_array which would be equal to the parameter i_number? Sorry, if I am making this more confusing. But, all I need to figure out is how can I have the user input some random numbers and output sorted list of those numbers.

Comment: If the user is inputting them they aren't really random... 8-) PL/SQL isn't really designed for user interaction, so this doesn't really make sense to me. It would be easy for *you* to generate `i_number` random numbers and then sort them, but for the user to supply them you'd either need to have that many parameters to the call or rely on the client's behaviour, e.g. prompting for substitution variables at run-time.

Comment: As mentioned above, my skills with PL/SQL is almost little to none. Sorry if my question doesn't make sense to you. But, I appreciate your answer. Since you mentioned that it would be easy to generate i_number random numbers and then sort them, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: @Noel The link you provided doesn't work. Is there an alternative link that you can provide?

Comment: @RK2013.. check this for sorting using simply SQL. http://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/31/sorting-plsql-collections-the-quite-simple-way-part-two-have-the-sql-engine-do-the-heavy-lifting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is really what you want, but if you do actually want to generate random numbers yourself and just want the length of the list to be supplied by the user (as `i_number`) then you can loop to do that:

```
...
BEGIN

  --Generate some random numbers
  for i in 1..i_number loop
    l_array.extend;
    l_array(i) := dbms_random.value(1, 100);
  end loop;

  --Loop through numbers and re-arrange their order using bubble sort---

  FOR i in 1 .. l_array.Count - 1 LOOP
  ...
```

When called with an `i_number` parameter value of 5 that might give:

```
The new sorted numbers are: 10
The new sorted numbers are: 55
The new sorted numbers are: 60
The new sorted numbers are: 74
The new sorted numbers are: 87
```

The parameters to the `dbms_random.value()` call are restricting the range of 'random' numbers that are generated.

Comment: I think this will work for now. It seems very close to what I am trying to accomplish. But, I will keep looking for alternatives as well. Thanks for your help! I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that I ended up with finally. Just wanted to share with you guys!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_BubbleSort1(i_number IN VARCHAR2)
IS
  --Local variables
  l_temp NUMBER;
  type l_array_type IS TABLE OF NUMBER(10);
  l_array l_array_type;
BEGIN
  --Parse values and dump into collections
  SELECT TRIM(SUBSTR(txt,
                 INSTR(txt, ',', 1, level) + 1,
                 INSTR(txt, ',', 1, level + 1) -
                 INSTR(txt, ',', 1, level) - 1)) BULK COLLECT
  INTO l_array
  FROM (select ',' || i_number || ',' AS txt FROM DUAL)
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(i_number) - LENGTH(replace(i_number, ',', '')) + 1;

  --Loop through numbers and re-arrange their order using bubble sort
  FOR i in 1 .. l_array.LAST - 1
  LOOP
    FOR j IN 2 .. l_array.LAST
    LOOP
      IF l_array(j) > l_array(j - 1) THEN
        l_temp := l_array(j - 1);
        l_array(j - 1) := l_array(j);
        l_array(j) := l_temp;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
  --Print the newly sorted numbers
  FOR k IN reverse 1 .. l_array.LAST
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The new sorted numbers are: ' || l_array(k));
  END Loop;
END;
```